# Make done button in the UINavigationBar appear when the row in UITableView is selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to make a done button appear UINavigationBar when any row in my UITableView is selected and I want this button to perform an action `performSegueWithIdentifier`.
Any ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
//add done button to navigation bar
UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(userPressedDone)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBarButtonItem;
```

Then have a method like this somewhere in your view controller:

```
-(void)userPressedDone {
    //perform segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that in your `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method you would add a `UIBarButtonItem` to the right or left bar button item of the `navigationItem` of your view controller.

Comment: And how about making it to performSegueWithIdentifier?

Comment: Have it call a method that does that.